# Logging whenever a file is read, written

Tags: linux, security, unix

Due to security requirements, I need to keep a log file of whenever any file on the system is read or written. The log file would look like this:

```
file - time - user
```

How would this be done?

Comment: I think you need to specify whether you are looking for an approach how to develop a tool or are you looking for an existing tool?

Comment: I wonder, will you log writing to your logfile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See if `auditd` works for you - http://linux.die.net/man/8/auditd

Answer (score 1):

You could also consider using [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify)